# "ignoring file...building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64"

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to archive an app, but this warning prevents me from doing so. I am new to app-development, so I am not sure how to fix this. I have looked at other questions and answers, but they do not seem to apply. Does anyone have any ideas? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does this result in? Is it a warning message or an error?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure in you build settings, Architecture is set to "Standard Architecture". And while starting to archive, build device is set to "Any iOS Device".

Comment: it doesn't help